# Plot a Numpy Array with (1, 2208, 2752, 3) Dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I have a microscopy array and I want to plot them.

The shape is:

```
(1, 2208, 2752, 3)
```

And Im triying it to plot with the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(image_array)
im.show()
```

And get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/envs/x/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2515, in fromarray
    mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
KeyError: ((1, 1, 2752, 3), '|u1')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/x/x/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    im = Image.fromarray(image_arrays)
  File "/Users/x/x/x/x/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2517, in fromarray
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

If I resize the array to  (2000,2000,3) this working, but with the 1 in the first dimension I have no Idea how can this work. The filetype is `.czi` and its a normal image.

Comment: Not sure how you are reading your image, but did you try:  `im = Image.fromarray(numpy.squeeze(image_array, axis=0)) `?

Comment: its working! Can you pls create an answer and explain your approach so I can it accept as a correct answer.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: the post is edited for full traceback

Comment: maybe `plt.imshow(image_array[0])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `x` by `y` by `(r,g,b)` matrix to display an image.  You seem to have a fourth dimension on your matrix, so I'm guessing whatever routine you are using to create the array is actually creating an array of images.

Since you only have one image, you can just remove the first axis using `image_array = numpy.squeeze(image_array, axis=0)`  This returns just the one image array in shape `(2208, 2752, 3)`. Alternately, you can do: `im = Image.fromarray(image_array[0])`

```
from PIL import Image
image_array = numpy.squeeze(image_array, axis=0)
im = Image.fromarray(image_array)
im.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try it now with a sample with more "images", e.g. I will check if can I get higher number as 1 in the first dimension.